# WordPress wp_enqueue_script not working after deregistering jQuery

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm developing a theme and trying to get wp_enqueue_script to work. The curious thing, is that nothing shows up. It doesn't do anything. Here's my setup:

in functions.php I have:

```
function named_scripts() {

    global $named_options;

    if( is_admin() ) return;

    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'screen', tz_JS . '/screen.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'screen' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', tz_JS . '/bootstrap/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    wp_register_style( 'custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-style.css', array(), '20120208', 'all' );  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style' );

}



add_action( 'init', 'named_scripts' );
```

in header.php I call

```
named_scripts();
```

And in the HTML, nothing shows up at all.

Comment: is there a particular reason why you deregister (= remove) jquery before you use it as dependency?

Comment: A few notes before I have to go: `add_action('wp_head', ...);` instead od `init`, make sure `wp_head();` is called in `header.php`, calling the `named_scripts();` function should be nessecary then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have registered your jquery file after remove the default wordpress jquery. I use this code.. hope it helps..

```
function load_external_jQuery() { // load external file  
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); // deregisters the default WordPress jQuery  
    wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('blur', get_template_directory_uri() . '/_/js/blur.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('blur');
}  
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_external_jQuery');
```

Answer (score 4):

Gerald is spot on.  You've deregistered the jQuery that comes with Wordpress without registering an alternative version.

Normally the shipped version is removed if you want to load it directly from a CDN.  An example would be below;

```
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.7.2');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

If you want to deregister it you need to register another version straight away before enqueing other JS dependant on jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Is the constant "tz_JS" is defined correctly?  Presuming yes, you should be able to simplify your function like so:

```
function named_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'screen', tz_JS . '/screen.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', tz_JS . '/bootstrap/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-style.css', array(), '20120208', 'all' );  

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'named_scripts' );
```

`wp_enqueue_scripts` is the proper hook to use for loading front-end scripts ([see Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)).  You don't need to check `is_admin()` since `admin_enqueue_scripts` is the corresponding hook for loading scripts on the admin side.

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing a **child theme** use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` when loading js within your theme directory.

```
function named_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script(
        'default_scripts', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0',
        false
        );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'named_scripts' );
```