# jQuery not working on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I built this simple search function for a FAQ page that displays live results and it works great locally and on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y8mkF/7/

However, I can not get it to work on Wordpress. Here's what I've tried so far:

Inserting the html portion into Wordpress text field.

I tried putting the javascript inside the post area as well by using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/search.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
updatepage();
//--></script>
```

and still it will not work. Is there a special way to put custom jQuery into Wordpress or what? It should not be this hard. I appreciate anyone's help on this. Thank you.

Comment: try using `jQuery` instead of `$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your `functions.php` file,

```
function load_jQuery() { // load external file  
    wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('search', get_template_directory_uri() . '/_/js/search.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('search');
}  
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_jQuery');
```

Source from [Wordpress wp_enqueue_script Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606823/wordpress-wp-enqueue-script-not-working)

Comment: He should also make sure to degregister the built-in version of jQuery when using this approach, to avoid conflicts: `wp_deregister_script('jquery');` above the first `wp_register_script`

Answer (score 0):

wordpress do not allow insert script into post, you can edit your theme to include script.